# What's the difference between : У меня́ бы́ло немно́го рабо́ты and У меня́ не́ было мно́го рабо́ты.?

Tags: грамматика

What's the difference between : У меня́ бы́ло немно́го рабо́ты  and  У меня́ не́ было мно́го рабо́ты. ?

Answer (score 2):

The difference is the same as in other languages using different types of negation. Negation usually emphasizes the following  word.  When the verb is positive

> *У меня было немного работы*(I had little work )

the focus is on the **amount** of work, that you still worked though not much.

When the verb is negative

> *У меня не было много работы*(I didn't have much work, I didn't work much),

it means you weren't busy much. The focus is on the **action**.

Answer (score 0):

У меня́ бы́ло немно́го рабо́ты = I had some work to do.

У меня́ не́ было мно́го рабо́ты. = I had quite a lot of spare time.